# Why is anime.js example not working when I use the code but works on codepen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, anime.js

So, I have been trying to work with an amazing animation from anime.js, [which is this one](https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/LMrRNW).

But this animation does not work when I use it after copying the code but it works on codepen. I have taken the code exactly as it is.

Following is how I added anime.js and other js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/75efae7724dbc3c055e918057fc4aca5"></script>
    <script src="anime-master/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sphere.js"></script>
```

`sphere.js` is the file that has the js code from codepen. And everything else is exactly the same. Is there anything I am doing wrong or I am missing here.
I would really appreciate any help.

After inspecting the following js code of the animation, the error states:

> UncaughtReferenceError anime is not defined 
>   at `anime.set()` part of the following code.

```
function fitElementToParent(el, padding) {
    var timeout = null;
    function resize() {
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        anime.set(el, {scale: 1});
        var pad = padding || 0;
        var parentEl = el.parentNode;
        var elOffsetWidth = el.offsetWidth - pad;
        var parentOffsetWidth = parentEl.offsetWidth;
        var ratio = parentOffsetWidth / elOffsetWidth;
        timeout = setTimeout(anime.set(el, {scale: ratio}), 10);
    }
    resize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
}

var sphereAnimation = (function() {

    var sphereEl = document.querySelector('.sphere-animation');
    var spherePathEls = sphereEl.querySelectorAll('.sphere path');
    var pathLength = spherePathEls.length;
    var hasStarted = false;
    var aimations = [];

    fitElementToParent(sphereEl);

    var breathAnimation = anime({
        begin: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < pathLength; i++) {
                aimations.push(anime({
                    targets: spherePathEls[i],
                    stroke: {value: ['rgba(255,75,75,1)', 'rgba(80,80,80,.35)'], duration: 500},
                    translateX: [2, -4],
                    translateY: [2, -4],
                    easing: 'easeOutQuad',
                    autoplay: false
                }));
            }
        },
        update: function(ins) {
            aimations.forEach(function(animation, i) {
                var percent = (1 - Math.sin((i * .35) + (.0022 * ins.currentTime))) / 2;
                animation.seek(animation.duration * percent);
            });
        },
        duration: Infinity,
        autoplay: false
    });

    var introAnimation = anime.timeline({
        autoplay: false
    })
        .add({
            targets: spherePathEls,
            strokeDashoffset: {
                value: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
                duration: 3900,
                easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
                delay: anime.stagger(190, {direction: 'reverse'})
            },
            duration: 2000,
            delay: anime.stagger(60, {direction: 'reverse'}),
            easing: 'linear'
        }, 0);

    var shadowAnimation = anime({
        targets: '#sphereGradient',
        x1: '25%',
        x2: '25%',
        y1: '0%',
        y2: '75%',
        duration: 30000,
        easing: 'easeOutQuint',
        autoplay: false
    }, 0);

    function init() {
        introAnimation.play();
        breathAnimation.play();
        shadowAnimation.play();
    }

    init();

})();
```

Comment: Check the console. Most likely you have an error resulting from a difference in the configuration

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added the console error too, sorry for the delay in edting

Comment: Why codepen url in a script tag?

Comment: @kiranvj removing or adding that does not change anything, but I read at one SO answer that it is needed as there might be this file that has the code which is missing from our version

Answer (score 0):

Remove this, you dont need it.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/75efae7724dbc3c055e918057fc4aca5"></script>`

Below line is not working for you

```
<script src="anime-master/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
```

1. Check if path `anime-master/lib/anime.min.js` is correct
2. Check for 404 errors in console
3. Execute all you JavaScript in window.load or `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: So, I did remove it and add the `document.on('load', function()) `.. because ready() is now deprecated, but I am still not getting the animation though, only the sphere. Also, I downloaded the zip as mentioned on the github page and using the correct path to anime.min.js but the animation is not working

Comment: `$(document).on('load', function() {  put all ur js code here });` ; in console, just type `anime` and enter, what do you see?.

Comment: Also try if this works `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

try moving your js codes that interacted with anime.js to the html file like these one

```
var animation = anime.timeline({...})
animation.add({...})
```

so in your case you have to move your sphere variable to the html file,and it would look like this

```
<html>
...
  <script src="your_other_js_file.js"></script>
  <script>
    var sphereAnimation = (function() {

          //your code here

    })();
  </script>
...
</html>
```

this fixes my issue, i don't really know why it worked just by moving it from js file to html, but for now this temporal fix will do

also i'm pretty sure that, there is a better way of doing this